# Finding a string pattern and printing the following characters for multiple occurrences in Python 3

Tags: python, loops, printing

I have just restarted programming after 10 years and now I am trying to learn Python. I am doing a Biochemistry degree and want to use programming to analyse DNA sequences. I need to find all "ga", "gc", "gg" and "gt" patterns in a sequence and copy the 3 bases downstream and the 3 bases upstream the two target bases (ga, gc, etc.). It was quite simple to achieve it to this point. However I need to continue the search in the sequence as my little script just give me the first occurrence:

```
seq = 'cacacgtccgccggccctcagagcccgagcgacttccgccccaggccaccgtccacccgcagaaacgcgccgacccacact'

if 'ga' in seq:
    locSplicing = seq[seq.find('ga')-3:seq.find('ga')+5]
    print(locSplicing)

if 'gg' in seq:
    locSplicing = seq[seq.find('gg')-3:seq.find('gg')+5]
    print(locSplicing)

if 'gt' in seq:
    locSplicing = seq[seq.find('gt')-3:seq.find('gt')+5]
    print(locSplicing)

if 'gc' in seq:
    locSplicing = seq[seq.find('gc')-3:seq.find('gc')+5]
    print(locSplicing)
```

Output:

```
tcagagcc
gccggccc
cacgtccg
tccgccgg
```

The code it is not sophisticated enough, I know, but I am still a beginner. I am not sure if I should continue using this script or use another method as findall or match and then use a loop (for or while) to print out all occurrences (not only the first ones). Can someone just give me a direction, please? Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to tweak it a bit to handle when you're at the beginning/end of your string, but here something that will find you the three predecessors and successors for every match.

```
>>> import re
>>> seq = 'cacacgtccgccggccctcagagcccgagcgacttccgccccaggccaccgtccacccgcagaaacgcgccgacccacact'
```

Indexes

```
>>> [i.start() for i in re.finditer('ga', seq)]
[20, 26, 30, 61, 71]
```

Matches +/- 3 elements

```
>>> [seq[index-3:index+5] for index in [i.start() for i in re.finditer('ga', seq)]]
['tcagagcc', 'cccgagcg', 'agcgactt', 'gcagaaac', 'gccgaccc']
```

Now that was just for matches with substring 'ga'. You can expand one more time to get the matches for the other substrings.

```
>>> [[seq[index-3:index+5] for index in [i.start() for i in re.finditer(s, seq)]] for s in l]
[['tcagagcc', 'cccgagcg', 'agcgactt', 'gcagaaac', 'gccgaccc'],
 ['gccggccc', 'ccaggcca'],
 ['cacgtccg', 'accgtcca'],
 ['gccggccc', 'ccaggcca']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer. That is cleaner and more sophisticate. I am just loving how smart Python is (I learned programming in Cobol when I was 15). 

I am actually opening a file instead using the variable seq as the sequences are huge. I have now to print it out in another file. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you for editing the last part. I am now creating the list of substrings.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. The recent edit was because I apparently do not know the difference between `2` and `3` :)

Comment: I bet it was the keyboard's fault :-)